# Fixed header & footer with auto-height, scrolling content?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to layout a grid with an always-visible, fixed-position header and footer and a content element that expands to fit the remainder of the container's height with a scrollbar inside.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">Header Text</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="row1">Content</div>
    <div id="row2">Content</div>
    <div id="row3">Content</div>
    <div id="row4">Content</div>
    <div id="row5">Content</div>
    <div id="row6">Content</div>
    <div id="row7">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer Text</div>
</div>
```

I can work this fine and simple if I set a fixed height on #content but in larger resolutions, I want #content to fill out the white space.

Another caveat; the height on #container, #header, and #footer are unknown.

jQuery is a possibility.

**EDIT: This bit worked out for me, adapted from Senad's answer;**

```
function resizeGrid() {
    $("div.items").innerHeight(0);
    $("div.items").innerHeight($(window).height() - $("body").innerHeight() - 22)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#header { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100px; }
#footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; height: 100px; }
#content { margin-top: 100px;
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   resizeContent();
  //attach on resize event
   $(window).resize(function() {
       resizeContent();
    });
});
function resizeContent()
{
   $('#content').attr('height', $(window).height() - $('#header').height() - $('#footer').height();
}
```

I hope this will help you:

Answer (score 1):

```
#header,
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background:#ccc;
    position:fixed
}

#header {top:0}
#footer {bottom:0}

html, body {height:100%}
```

Pure css, no js :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean fixed. If you mean always on the page, then:

```
#header, #footer { position: fixed; height 150px; }
#content { margin: 150px 0px; }
```

Any background should go on the body element

If you mean at bottom at top of content, then you just need a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

If you mean that the header and footer are auto-height, and you want them at a fixed point on the page at all times, then you'll want jQuery since there is not an easy cross-browser solution.

```
$('#content').css({marginTop: $('#header').outerHeight(), marginBottom: $('#footer').outerHeight() });
```