# Header + map + footer using 100% height

Tags: css

A want to create a page for an app. My header and footer have a fixed height and I need to put a map between them filling 100% of the remaining height.
I've tried many solutions, without any success.
Thanks
JM

UPDATE
I would like to use something like this : http://polyetilen.lt/en/android-geolocation-application-demo-using-phonegap-jquery-mobile-and-google-maps
But without jQuery, just simple and short CSS.

Comment: This looks like a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232035/fixed-header-footer-with-auto-height-scrolling-content)

Comment: Could you post what you have tried? We can't give solution for you if we don't know for problem

Comment: I've tried calc. It works with Chrome but not all in the app on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I would give the header and footer fixed position, and give the map padding on top and bottom to match the header/footer. You can use `box-sizing: border-box` (and vendor prefixes) and set the height to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/5hVY3/) using a bit of jquery. Can it suit for you?

```
var contentHeight = $("#map").height();
var newHeight = $(window).height() - $("#header").height() - $("#footer").height();
if (contentHeight < newHeight)
{
    $("#map").css("height", newHeight + "px");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have the height resizing automatically when a change the size of the window ?

Comment: Add $(window).resize(sizeContent); based on jsFiddle example