# How to fix navbar & footer in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I make the navbar and footer fixed.

Image shown:

[image]

Comment: Jquery will do it ...........

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232035/fixed-header-footer-with-auto-height-scrolling-content

Answer (score 4):

Here we go

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar"></div>
<div id="body-content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar,
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background:#ccc;
    position:fixed
}

#navbar {top:0}
#footer {bottom:0}

html, body {height:100%}
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vinizinmoraes/DGdYq/)

Comment: I would prefer instead of html, body {..} -> #body-content {position: relative; margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom: 5%; padding: 5px; z-index:-1;}

Comment: @zeyorama that is a way to do it too... the only thing I would change is the margin-top and margin-bottom value to be the same as navbar and footer height

Comment: yeah of couse navbar and footer height   good point!!

Answer (score 0):

Use 3 divs with absolute positions.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header, #content, #footer { position absolute; left: 0; right: 0 }
#header { top: 0; height: 200px; }
#content { top: 200px; bottom: 200px; overflow-y: auto; }
#footer { bottom: 0; height: 200px;}
```

But avoid this if possible. You will have issues with small screens and content overflowing on header and footer.

Comment: `position: fixed` would be appropriate.

Comment: Depends where he wants the scroll

Comment: The scroll should stay on the body for the best accessibility. Forcing a scroll on a sub element is liable to cause more problems than it solves.