# Offset content top margin based on height of fixed header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a header which is fixed. Therefore it has been taken out of the flow of the HTML and the content now sits at the top of the page underneath the header. I can't just give #main-content a margin-top because I don't know the height of the header because it varies depending on screen size. How can I make the margin-top responsive to the height of the header?

```
<div class="header-fixed">
<h1>Logo</h1>
<nav>Home about contact</nav>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
<p>The content at the top is underneath the header
</p>
</div>
```

Please see my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gapugs8u/1/)

Comment: you can use javascript!

Comment: Please provide some code, e.g. via jsfiddle.net. If you know the size, you could simple use `margin-*` or `padding-*`. Otherwise Javascript.

Comment: Second the request for a jsfiddle. "header varies on depending upon the sites [sic] width" is ambiguous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed header & footer with auto-height, scrolling content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232035/fixed-header-footer-with-auto-height-scrolling-content)

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity I hope I have cleared things up with the JS fiddle. I don't believe It is a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With jQuery, you can use [`.resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/), [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), and [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(document.body).css("margin-top", $(".header-fixed").height());
}).resize();
```

Comment: Please may you explain this further I am a novice with Jquery. I have included a JSfiddle which has the specific class names and IDs

Comment: It's adding an event handler to `onresize` of the `window`, so that when the page initially loads or resizes, it sets the `margin-top` of the page to be the height in pixels of `header-fixed`. Does that make sense? I would recommend the [W3Schools jQuery tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) if you haven't formally learned jQuery yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the resize event

```
$(window).resize(function(){
var height = $('.header-fixed').height();//take the header height
$('.main-content').css({'margin-top':height});//alter the margin of the wrapped content
}).trigger('resize');//trigger the margin resize when page is loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help I got it working using:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#main-content').css("margin-top", $(".header-fixed").height());
}).resize();
});
</script>
```